# How to securely reference a .json private key file from a Java app running on Google Cloud

Tags: java, security, google-cloud-platform, private-key

I'm working on an app that will run on the Google Cloud Platform, and it needs to authenticate to the Google Admin 'Directory' SDK. The recommended approach that everyone (including Google) seems to suggest, is to create a service account in the Google Cloud Platform, and use the private key credentials for the service account to authenticate within the app that's running on Google Cloud Platform. Here is Google's recommended approach:

[Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

To summarise the approach, for a Java app it requires the following:

- Upload the private key file to a file location available application (the private key file can be JSON instead of P12 as suggested in the above guide)
- Programatically load the file in the application, and use its credentials to authenticate

My question is this - if the file is directly uploaded to the src/main/resources folder for the application that runs on the Google Cloud Platform, is this is a significant security risk? How easy would it be for a hacker to access the file? If it's a risk, then what is a secure alternative to this approach?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. And the second is that is impossible for us to know.

Comment: Thanks @Elliot Frisch. I've modified the question slightly to ask about a recommended approach, if the approach described is unacceptable. I've done a bit of research and apart from advice to exclude the JSON file from source control I haven't come across a recommendation for how the authentication should be securely performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this answer I will assume that you are running on Google Compute Engine. The same type of answer will apply to App Engine, Containers, Kubernetes and Cloud Functions.

> My question is this - if the file is directly uploaded to the
>   src/main/resources folder for the application that runs on the Google
>   Cloud Platform, is this is a significant security risk?

This is a security risk and is a very poor security practice. Numerous prominent companies have been breached with credentials stored in source code.

> How easy would it be for a hacker to access the file?

Unknown. There are many different types of breaches. If a hacker obtains shell access to your instance you are in serious trouble. If a hacker obtains root shell access, they can do almost anything they want.

> If it's a risk, then what is a secure alternative to this approach?

**Best practices for security regarding credentials: do not store credentials in your source code or on your computing resources.**

Normally you would access your credentials from Compute Engine Metadata server. These credentials are created by Google Cloud when your instance starts up. You can control these permissions in the Google Console under "Cloud API access scopes" OR via a service account that you specify for the VM.

However, with G-Suite, you need to create delegated credentials. I do not recommend mixing the credentials that are used by your VM with the credentials used for G-Suite. This means that you still need access to credentials in Json format (or P12 for legacy applications).

Since best security practices are to not store these credentials in source code or on the instance, you need to store them securely someplace else that you can access securely. One option is Google Cloud Storage. Assign a Cloud Storage read-only scope to your instance so that you can read the credentials Json file from Cloud Storage. Read the credentials using your SDK directly into memory and do not involve disk operations or utilities such as `gsutil`. I recommend that you create a seperate bucket for privileged files such as credentials.

Note that you are using several credentials. 1) the credentials stored in Google's metadata server. 2) the credentials that you download from Cloud Storage. 3) the delegated credentials that you create to access G-Suite and other Google applications.

The first set of credentials (Application Default Credentials - ADC) are used for normal cloud access including reading the second set of credentials from Cloud Storage. The third set are created in your software.

The credentials that you store on Cloud Storage do not need any privileges except domain wide delegation. The privileges are added via scopes when you create the G-Suite credentials (credentials #3).

Note: Do not store the email address used for delegated credentials in your source code. Store this in another Json file on Cloud Storage.